# Is an ID needed to be named on a will in Thailand?

Tags: legal, thailand

My dad (a UK national) lives in Thailand and owns property there. He's getting a will written and naming me as the beneficary. Whoever is writing the will has asked him for my details such as name and address (I'm fine with that) but also a photo of my passport. I immediately questioned this, as it is obviously potentially the first step towards having ID fraud committed against me, and I've never needed to provide this when being named in wills in the UK.

However, I am aware that Thailand is particularly bureaucratic, especially where foreigners are concerned, and neither would it surprise me if this is a requirement.

Can someone confirm if needing to provide a photo of my passport (or other ID such as driving licence) is normal in Thailand if being named in a will?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it were indeed required. As you say, Thailand is very bureaucratic, and possibly even more so with foreigners. Since it's an important procedure, I would advise you to go there and check things out for yourself.

Comment: @dda Going there isn't really an option :) I did enquire of the Thai embassy in London, who to their credit did respond, but with a non-comittal "maybe it is, maybe it isn't" answer. I checked out the law firm, who seem to have a decent online presence, specialise in wills for expats in Thailand and at least looks legit, so I went with it hoping my Dad has better judgement than I gave him credit for.

Comment: Let's hope for the best! Laws regarding real estate are also very complex, and could even be regarded as unfair. Foreigners cannot own more than 49% of a piece of real estate, for example.

Comment: @dda I believe you can get round that by incorporating a shell company.